# wxPython menu text alignment

Tags: python, menu, wxpython, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm developing a wxPython GUI, and would like to right-align shortcut text. Obviously one can cludge this using tab characters, but I'd prefer to do it natively if there is a way to.

The default menu item creation is thus:

```
menu = wx.Menu()
item_id = 1
item_name = 'My menu item'
help_text = 'Clicking this does something interesting.'
item = menu.Append(item_id, item_name, help_text)
```

I'll be expanding on this with shortcuts, so if I were using tabs, it would be something like:

```
item_name = 'My menu item\t\tCtrl+Alt+H'
```

However, that involves a lot of manual `\t` entries to make sure everything lines up, and anytime a menu item changes name or another item is added, they would all potentially need to be updated. Is there any way around this, e.g. a class method I'm not seeing to automatically associate the keybinding to the menu item?

**Edit:** I know that when passing text like `&My menu item`, it does *something* automatically with the keybinding associated with the ID specified if there is a definition associated with that ID in the accelerators table, correct?

Comment: See below for the answer. If someone does a better writeup than my own in the next two days, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went digging through a couple other application's code to find the answer. It turns out the default behavior with `\t` doesn't do what it *looks* like it would do (i.e. insert a tab character), but is sensibly interpreted by the toolkit as doing precisely what I wanted to do. Thus, the way to right-align a short cut is simple: create it with the text you desire, followed by `\t<shortcut>` (rather as I had above). In the example code I pasted above, if I wanted my shortcut to be `Ctrl + T`, it should therefore be thus:

```
menu = wx.Menu()
item_id = 1
item_name = 'My menu item\tCtrl+T'
help_text = 'Clicking this does something interesting.'
item = menu.Append(item_id, item_name, help_text)
```

**Edit:** updated the following section based on Mike Driscoll's [very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15554665/564181).

Note that this creates the shortcut binding (wxPython picks that up), but it doesn't make it selectable using e.g. the Alt key on Windows.

You can associate the Alt key to quickly open the menu and navigate to it by using the ampersand in your `item_name` text, but you'll still need to associate the desired keybinding manually via the `AcceleratorTable`:

```
menu = wx.Menu()
item_id = 1

# Ctrl+T is bound to the keybinding
accelerator_table = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('T'), item_id)])
self.setAcceleratorTable(accelerator_table)

# Ctrl+T is not included, but the menu item can be accessed via Alt key
item_name = '&My menu item'

help_text = 'Clicking this does something interesting.'
item = menu.Append(item_id, item_name, help_text)
```

This, I imagine, would actually be the preferred pattern, as then anywhere that the `item_id` was referenced, the shortcut could be referenced automatically. This would also make for seamless updates.

Answer (score 1):

While Chris is right about "\t" indenting the keybinding correctly in the menu, I don't really see what he means by *automatically* associating anything using an ampersand. The ampersand (&) DOES allow the used to type ALT to get the File menu to open and then if you type another letter that has had the ampersand applied to it, it will jump to that menu item, but the & does not connect the menu item to the accelerator table. That is done via the menu item's ID.

See the following code:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "wx.Menu Tutorial")

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        exitId = wx.NewId()
        exitMenuItem = fileMenu.Append(exitId, "&Exit/tCtrl+X",
                                       "Exit the application")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onExit, id=exitId )
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL,  ord('X'), exitId )])
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onExit(self, event):
        """"""
        self.Close()

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note that the **exitId** is used to create the menu item, bind the menu item to EVT_MENU and finally, it is used in the AcceleratorTable so the user can use the shortcut key.

Here are a few references that might be helpful:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/07/02/wxpython-working-with-menus-toolbars-and-accelerators/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/WorkingWithMenus
- http://zetcode.com/wxpython/menustoolbars/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/02/wxpython-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerators/

Comment: Awesome, and thanks. I'll tweak my own answer to be more accurate in light of the info you've provided here, too.

Comment: Note that the only reason I haven't yet accepted this as the answer is because it's more a response to my initial answer than an explicit answer to the question.

Comment: No problem. I didn't want to re-write everything you said as that seemed like I'd be stealing your answer, so I just created an "addendum" answer